# Retrieve all images at once or individually from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have a number of images that are stored as `VARBINARY(MAX)` (using FileStream) in a database. I'm looking to retrieve about 10 images or so at a time.

The prescribed, most common way using ASP.net is to use an HTTP handler and hit the database for each individual image. Seems fine, but is a bit slow at times.

Is it best to download all images for a given page at the same time in one big data chunk? Or should I try to grab each individually? Best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best to do them individually on a domain that doesn't have cookies set, or make sure your handler will work with multiple simultaneous requests.  That way you can stream multiple results from the DB at the same time, and stream multiple images from your webserver as it gets them.

Comment: Very interesting.. so the handler would allow me to do multiple simulataneous requests?.. can you elaborate?

Comment: Is there any disadvantage to the 'get them all at once' approach?

Comment: @user111222333 There could be disadvantages such as IOPs usage per my post, but SQL server handles that very well, and designed for retrieval of large data sets. In your case we are talking about 10 images which indicates that the overhead would simply be not much. However, simultaneous connections is a bad option in my opinion, as SQL likes SET Type of operations(data sets rather than loops) better. I would recommend you running the performance  analyzer and see the difference.

Comment: @user111222333 The disadvantage is that by querying a big set like that, you are essentially single-threading the request.  You can't start receiving the second image until the first image has been transferred, and writing it optimally so that you can start sending the images as you receive them from the database rather than waiting for the entire set is more difficult and more complex.

Comment: @user111222333  You should benchmark it with realistic tests, taking into account client/server bandwidth and latency and workload.  Then see how each responds as you scale up.  I have not (yet) run into a scaling issue doing single requests at a time, even on some very large websites.  That said, we rely on 3rd party code to handle the image retrieval, caching because it's simply more cost effective to do so than write it from scratch.  Currently, we use code from http://imageresizing.net/ for this purpose, and it hasn't let us down yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

I think many people would have different opinions, and reasons about what the best practice is for them, but in reality, it all depends on hardware, software, data structure, and if the data is normalized.

In general, the SQL server likes SET operations better, meaning, the loops in general are slower.But, loops are safer for IOPs related issues, and they are better at causing less locks.

I am not sure which object mapper, or built in SQL library you are using( I have a feeling you may be using LINQ after you built a SQL class), but it also depends on the library you are using, and I would definitely recommend dapper.

I think reading them all at once would be faster, and here is why;
 - If it is as you say, and you hit the database each time for the image, then that would add the delay of reconnecting to the database, so the latency will occur. But when there is one connection, the data retrieval is straight and your connection is open at that moment without requiring further session authentication.

I would recommend downloading them all at once, and informing the end user with a download screen during the process of that. Also for retrieving data, this link is very helpful I believe : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(v=sql.100).aspx

Depending on the features of your server, and edition, you could definitely use different features.

Comment: I'm working with normalized data. No SQL loops, this will all be done in a single SELECT statement that returns 10 VARBINARY(MAX) columns. The other approach is single SELECT statements that each hit the database, etc.

Comment: I agree with your thoughts of reconnecting/latency. The real issue is this: With an HTTP Handler, the only real way of doing this in ASP.net is to hit the database for each image. You provide an image ID in a querystring to the handler, it hits the DB for the image and you get the result. Just seems silly. With jQuery/ajax and a Web Method, I can get all images, but it's a pain to write this code and complexifies the whole issue.

Comment: It's really slapstick workaround to what should be a simpler problem.

Comment: Can you please comment on the other answer?

Comment: How many images are we talking about? Do you have an ID range? If you have an ID range, just request the images between that ID range.